# Custom header template for ui-grid , angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I was trying [angular's ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial) for a project but finding it difficult to built a custom template for my grid . When I checked the source code , I got the below html template I saved it to a file , header-template.html and referenced it while configuring the grid.

```
<div class="ui-grid-header">
  <div class="ui-grid-top-panel">
    <div ui-grid-group-panel="" ng-show="grid.options.showGroupPanel" class="">
      <div class="ui-grid-group-panel ng-scope">
        <div ui-t="groupPanel.description" class="description " ng-show="groupings.length == 0">
          Drag a column header here and drop it to group by that column.</div>
        <ul ng-show="groupings.length > 0" class="ngGroupList ">
          <!-- ngRepeat: group in configGroups -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">
      <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">
         <!--ngRepeat: col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name -->
        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell clearfix" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" ui-grid-header-cell="" col="col" render-index="$index" ng-style="$index === 0 &amp;&amp; colContainer.columnStyle($index)">
          <div ng-class="{ 'sortable': sortable }" class="sortable">
            <div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex">
              <span class="">{{col.colDef.name}}</span>
              <span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }" class="ui-grid-invisible ui-grid-icon-blank">&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
            <!-- ngIf: grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false -->
            <!-- ngRepeat: colFilter in col.filters -->
            <!-- ngIf: filterable -->
            <div ng-if="filterable" class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters">
              {{colFilter}}
              <input type="text" class="ui-grid-filter-input" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}" placeholder="">
              <div class="ui-grid-filter-button" ng-click="colFilter.term = null">
                <i class="ui-grid-icon-cancel right" ng-show="!!colFilter.term">&nbsp;</i>
                <!-- use !! because angular interprets 'f' as false -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end ngIf: filterable --><!-- end ngRepeat: colFilter in col.filters -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ui-grid-menu="" class=""><!-- ngIf: shown -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have specified the gridOptions by

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'gridData',
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: $scope.columnDef,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    headerTemplate:'views/header-template.html'
  };
```

But for some reason , I dont know why , I m getting this , as shown in the image . The template gets printed once again , below the template that I try to build

[image]

Please help ..

Comment: how do you define the `gridOptions` and it's possible to put your code in plunker?

Comment: @elaijuh Could you check now . ?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve for your header?

Comment: @elaijuh : I am actually using ui-grid as a replacement for slick-grid ,But I wanted to maintain the look & feel of slick grid at the maximum . Please refer this [http://og-web-www.s3.amazonaws.com/01-opengamma-webgl-surface.fullsize.png] . For now , I am trying to obtain the input box with the placeholder text

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To obtain what I was trying to achieve I had to specify a headerCellTemplate(Not headerTemplate) within the columnDefs of the grid as given below :

```
          {
        field: key, displayName: key
        , headerCellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{ \'sortable\': sortable }">' +
      '<div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div>' +
      '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex">' +
      '<span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-icon-up-dir\': col.sort.direction == asc, \'ui-grid-icon-down-dir\': col.sort.direction == desc, \'ui-grid-icon-blank\': !col.sort.direction }">' +
      '&nbsp;' +
      '</span>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false" class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" ng-click="toggleMenu($event)">' +
      '<i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down">&nbsp;</i>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div ng-if="filterable" class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters">' +
      '<input type="text" class="ui-grid-filter-input" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-attr-placeholder="{{col.displayName || \'\'}}" />' +
      '<div class="ui-grid-filter-button" ng-click="colFilter.term = null">' +
      '<i class="ui-grid-icon-cancel" ng-show="!!colFilter.term">&nbsp;</i>' + <!-- use !! because angular interprets 'f' as false -->
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
      }
```

Because for ui-grid , headerCellTemplate is appended inside the headerTemplate .The default headerCellTemplate is provided in the following [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/packages/core/src/templates/ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell.html)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`headerTemplate` is to be preppended to `<div class="ui-grid-top-panel">` as a previous sibling to `<div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">`, so your `views/header-template.html` should only include:

```
<div ui-grid-group-panel="" ng-show="grid.options.showGroupPanel" class="">
  <div class="ui-grid-group-panel ng-scope">
    <div ui-t="groupPanel.description" class="description " ng-show="groupings.length == 0">
       Drag a column header here and drop it to group by that column.
    </div>
    <ul ng-show="groupings.length > 0" class="ngGroupList ">
          <!-- ngRepeat: group in configGroups -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

refer to this [official demo](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header)

Comment: @32teeths, sorry just update the link to offical demo which shows how to use `headerTemplate`

Comment: I am sorry , I am still not able to figure out .

Comment: @32teeths - nevermind, is it possible to paste your code to plunker?

Comment: I have uploaded the required code to http://plnkr.co/edit/KF13JRmAWbuqVBN6Bou2?p=catalogue .

Comment: can you also mock some data there

Comment: The official demo seems completely useless.